# Loolong for tusdt faucet Sepolia

Tags: testnets, sepolia

Found only one but it is not working . Can anyone please point out a working one.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you won’t find an official TUSD faucet for any testnet, only those made by developers.

The reason for this is that you require pools filled with liquidity, which you’re unlikely to get on testnets due to the effort of upkeep.

Best thing to do is probably get some testnet ETH, deploy the USDT contract [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code) on the testnet and use something like `transfer` to provide yourself with tokens.